# Ackermann robot gazebo simulation?

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Does anyone know of an existing ackermann robot available for use in gazebo? I require an ackermann robot for a simulation task but don't have the data to construct a replication of my own robot (inertial and dimensions). Just want to throw it on an ackermann robot and see how it goes  :)

Thanks, Grant

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330986/ackermann-robot-gazebo-simulation?/) by [PapaG](https://answers.ros.org/users/40565/papag/) on ROS Answers with karma: 161 on 2019-08-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2020-04-20**:
https://github.com/chrissunny94/ackerman_ros_robot_gazebo_simulation

I have cleaned up  the robotnik rbcar simulation .

Hope someone finds this useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I made one to teach students about Ackermann kinematics:

https://github.com/robustify/audibot

The control interface is throttle percentage, brake torque, and steering wheel angle. It attempts to implement as realistic of a dynamic response to those signals as possible. There are some example launch files in the repo to get you started.

---

Originally posted by [robustify](https://answers.ros.org/users/26169/robustify/) with karma: 956 on 2019-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SteadyStatError](https://answers.ros.org/users/72807/steadystaterror/) on 2021-04-01**:
Hi,

Did you have teleop file this model or how can i control the car model